# How do I change the MySQL data folder path in a Mac?

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x, datadir

How do I change the MySQL data folder path in a Mac?

- I am running OS X 10.10 & MySQL 5.6
- In Windows I can edit `datadir` in `my.ini`
- For Mac, mysqld does not have parameter for `--defaults-file=`

Comment: I think in MacOS, mysql uses the default values, without a config file. You just need to create a `/etc/my.cnf` file and restart MySQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/mysql-my-cnf-location

Answer (score 2):

First shutdown mysql

```
mysqladmin -uroot -p shutdown
```

Then, launch mysqld by hand

```
mysqld --defaults-file=...
```

or if MySQL is running with all defaults and you are just changing datadir, do this

```
mysqld --datadir=/path/to/mysql/data
```

Here is a [StackOverflow question (MySQL 'my.cnf' location?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/mysql-my-cnf-location) with multiple suggestions on where `my.cnf` might be for Mac OS when installed .

Comment: Thanks how can install a Service in mac like in windows mysqld --install myService --defaults-file=my.ini

Comment: Go to command line, and run `mysqld --help --verbose > mysqld.txt`. Look inside mysqld.txt. Do you see `--install` as a parameter option ?

Comment: no i do not see --install i think this command is just for windows